# JDBC Using an UPDATE FROM state

Tags: sql, tomcat, jdbc, derby

I'm trying to update a record from one of my tables with values from another table I have.

After looking up, I saw that an `UPDATE FROM STATE` should solve the problem, but after trying I get the error :

> Syntax error: Encountered "FROM" at line 1, column 67.

My tables(relevant fields):

> TABLE USERS: STRING nickName FLOAT logFollwers
>
> TABLE POSTS: STRING author FLOAT logRepub FLOAT popularity

My SQL query:

```
UPDATE POSTS SET popularity = POSTS.logRepub * USERS.logFollowers 
FROM POSTS INNER JOIN USERS ON POSTS.author=USERS.nickName
```

I hope that's all the needed information.
Thanks for your help.

EDIT: tried:

```
UPDATE POSTS SET popularity= (SELECT POSTS.logRepub * USERS.logFollowers FROM POSTS INNER JOIN USERS ON POSTS.author=USERS.nickName)
```

And got the error:

> "Scalar subquery is only allowed to return a single row."

When calling executeUpdate();

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What are the primary keys of the two tables?

Comment: For USERS: userName varchar(10) PRIMARY KEY, for POSTS: postID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY

Comment: Is nickname unique as well? What if `logFollowers` is `0`? do you want to add the `logRepub` value then? Or should the result be `0` as well?

Comment: logFollowers and logRebpub are set to 1 set default. nickname is indeed unique. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
UPDATE POSTS 
  SET popularity = logRepub * (SELECT u.logFollowers
                               FROM users u 
                               where u.username = posts.author);
```

You don't need a join in the sub-select, you only need a co-related sub-select.

You said `username` is the PK of the `users` table, however your example uses a column `nickname`. If nickname is not unique, this cannot be used as a co-related subquery.